# SharePoint Online - Is it Possible to Embed a Twitter Feed on a Modern Page / Modern Web Parts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-pages

Office 365 / SharePoint Online - Is it Possible to Embed a Twitter Feed on a Modern Page? I'm currently using a modern web part 'Embed', but having no luck so far.

Comment: This should be possible using SPFx webparts. Did you give it a try?

Comment: No I didn't, I'm not familiar with them.  Can you provide more information/links on these? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The [Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-content-to-your-page-using-the-Embed-web-part-13cc66b6-d0c8-4894-85a7-820c20143797) only support embedding content from secure websites. And SharePoint Online only support embedding content using the website address or iframe based embeds.

To [add a Twitter Feed to a SharePoint page](https://infrastructuretechnologypros.com/adding-a-twitter-feed-to-a-sharepoint-home-page/), we may need to add scripts (`<script>….</script>`) to the page.

Refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about customizing the modern experiences in SharePoint Online, we need to use [SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to add scripts to SharePoint modern pages.

Comment: add a Twitter Feed to a SharePoint page - the link is broken now. Do you have any other examples or info on how they did it?

Answer (score 1):

We could successfully embed YouTube videos but struggled with embedding a twitter feed. After little success we created a work around.  This may be of interest to others on how we did this:

We created a basic (HTML) webpage with only the following code from twitter (created through a twitter widget):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">National Park Tweets - Curated tweets by TwitterDev</a>
```

This new webpage is then using the same domain as our website.  On our SharePoint Online we embedded the 'Embed' modern webpart into our modern page and added the following code:

```
<iframe width="430" height="500" src="https://www.website.co.uk/twitter.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Voila!

Answer (score -2):

Just use this web part https://github.com/thenikhilk/sharepoint-instagram-feed.

No need for tokens, registration or any third party sign-in, just username you want to embed.